# In the square find $|DE|$

Tags: geometry

In the figure, $ABCD$ is a square with $|AD|=4cm,$ and $|AE|=3|EC|$. Find $|DE|$
Please help me.
[image]

My attempt: I find $AC=4 \square {2}$ but i didn't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Once $AC=4\sqrt{2}$ (because $AC$ is the diagonal of a square) then $AE=3\sqrt{2}$

[image]

Let's make $FE$ perpendicular to $AD$.

We also have $\angle EAF =45$ so $AF=FE$.

Once $AE=3\sqrt{2}$ then $AF=FE=3$ (use Pythagoras theorem).

Now we conclude that $DF=1$ and doing Pythagoras theorem at the triangle $DEF$ we get:

$$DE^2=DF^2+FE^2=1^2+3^2=10 \Rightarrow DE=\sqrt{10}$$

Comment: Thankyu very much sir, but the given example is the grade 2 in the high scholl where the cosine theorem It taught not therefore required with any simple way

Comment: take a look again. is that works?

Answer (score 1):

you have $EC=\sqrt 2$

now use cosine law

$DE^2=DC^2+EC^2-2\cdot DC\cdot EC\cdot cos45$

$\implies DE=\sqrt{10}$